# complex object is empty when use in Web API input

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a method in Web API that I used the object as input, but when I try to run the API using URI the fields inside the object are Null.

this is my method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("AddUser/{user}")]
    public async Task<string> CreateUser([FromUri]AddUser user)
    {
        //LoansApiTrace.Trace.Verbose(EventId.Start, () => string.Format("{0}: {1}", "AddUser", user.));
        string Exception = await Repository.AddUserAsync(user);
        return Exception;
    }
```

This is AddUser object:

```
 public class AddUser
    {     
    public string UserEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
    public string RemoteRefNumber { get; set; }
  }
```

and this is the URI:

```
http://localhost:59509/Adduser/user=test@yahoo.com,pass,salt,remref/
```

it goes to the method but UserEmailAddress , PasswordHash  ,..all 4 are empty.

Comment: Why would you put the object in the Uri rather than the body?

Comment: @RyanGates In a `GET`?

Comment: @KennethK. I don't think that `CreateUser` should be a `GET` at all. I would think that it would be a `POST`. I didn't look closely enough. Now that I did, it strikes me as odd.

Comment: Never use GET for operations that have side-effects. GET should always be [idempotent and safe](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/).

Comment: I agree with @FedericoDipuma. For creation, I would use POST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really a bad practice to pass secret data through URI like you're doing. Then I will not attempt to give a solution for that to work.

The best practice is to pass that kind of data through your request body and use Http POST method :

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("AddUser/{userId}")]
public async Task<string> CreateUser(string userId, [FromBody]AddUser user)
{
     // Find a user by userId
     // Then update the user data.
}
```

- you use an URI like this => http://localhost:59509/Adduser/12345 where 12345 is the user id.
- you need to make sure that the selected HTTP method is POST
- you need to write the data of `AddUser` into the request body

It also recommanded to use HTTPS when user need to send that type of data.

Answer (score 0):

**Consider Using `POST` If Applicable**

While it may not be do-able, you may want to consider adding these fields within a `<form>` and simply posting them to the server in the body as opposed to using the actual URL itself. Passwords, salts and hashes generally aren't something that you want to get passed around like that.

**If You Must  Use A `GET`**

Have you tried passing the values in as proper query-string parameters instead?

```
http://localhost:59509/Adduser/user?UserEmailAddress=test@yahoo.com&PasswordHash=abc&Salt=123&RemoteRefNumber=foo
```

This should set the following properties based on your current routes:

- **user** = "user"
- **UserEmailAddress** = "test@yahoo.com"
- **PasswordHash** = "abc"
- **Salt** = "123"
- **RemoteRefNumber** = "foo"

MVC has to have some idea of how to bind these properties to those on your class, so unless the names match as expected, it will not know how to map something like "user" to "UserEmailAddress". As mentioned earlier, this isn't ideal and can present all sorts of security issues (so only use something like this on prototype / non-production environments).

Comment: http://localhost:59509/AddUser/user?UserEmailAddress=test&PasswordHash=pas%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bs&Salt=salt&RemoteRefNumber=remref   this still give me null.